# Uses of Chlorine

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why in the reaction between sodium chlorate and water is chloric acid produced as well as Na+ and OH- ions. Shouldn't both the ions just react to produce NaOH?

Comment: What happens if you throw NaOH into water?

Comment: It splits into Na+ ions and OH- ions. But why wouldn't they combine to produce NaOH?

Comment: You have to make up your mind, because you can't have it split into ions *and* combine at the same time.

Comment: Well, H and OH manage to split and combine all at the same time. Detailed balance and whatnot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems at first that there are three materials involved, but then we subdivide them and sometimes lose track of what's important.

The first material mentioned is sodium chlorate. It is a solid, and if you could break it up into very tiny pieces, at last you would get Na+ ions and ClO3- ions (they could break apart further, but let's not be brutal).

The second material mentioned is water. Break it down to H2O molecules - a few break down further to H+ and OH- automatically, but only about once in 10 million times at pH=7.

The third material is the solution of sodium chlorate in water: sodium ions and chlorate ions dissolve and separate in water molecules (with a very few H+ and OH- ions). Chloric acid is a strong acid; in water the ClO3- doesn't tend to hold on to its H+ or grab H+ from water molecules, so extra OH- ions are not produced.

Overall, nothing much is happening beyond the dispersal of the Na+ and ClO3- ions into water and some association with individual water molecules that makes dissolution possible. If you evaporate the water, you get solid sodium chlorate back; there is no chloric acid produced or detectable.

Answer (score 0):

Na+ is more stable in water than in the form on NaOH.
The effective charge on Na+ is reduced because of the Oxygen in H2O. Therefore why will it prefer a less stable form?